# Total number of moderator flags per day

Tags: support, flags

What are the average number of moderator flags on SO per day? I generally feel like I'm flagging way more than the average user, but I'm basing that on the number of spam/offensive flags that come up, which is probably not a good baseline for how many moderator flags come up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say since none of us see all of them.  If one moderator clears a flag, it's gone from the queue.  I do know that the queue could get to <strike>20-25</strike> 100+ flags if none of us logged in for several hours on a weekday.

I wouldn't worry about flagging too much.  First, you're limited in the number of flags you can raise in a day.  Second, I could probably (but won't) name at least a dozen people who flag more than you do on SO.  Third, nobody has complained about you specifically (yet).  ;)

Comment: Only two dozen flags over several hours?  Now I feel like I flag far too often.

Comment: @Popular: If you're flagging things that need immediate attention or that only ♦ moderators can deal with, then don't worry about the number of flags you raise.  Even if you hit the limit every day, you'd really have to be flagging trivial stuff before it would be a problem.  I'm not aware of anyone who's even close to what would be considered abusing the moderator flagging system.  We'd rather have too many flags than not enough.

Comment: It's easy enough to say now, just check `/admin`, look at the number of posts that have been handled in the last month, and divide by the date.  However, this post is currently about 2 years out of date (I know it's far more than 100 now!) and will be out of date soon anyways.   Perhaps an answer which addresses the real question 'how much should I flag' would be more appropriate?

Comment: @KevinVermeer It's already addressed.  "First, you're limited in the number of flags you can raise in a day."