# Low quality flag with bounty. Flag declined

Tags: discussion, bounties, declined-flags

This 100 points bonty [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711616/how-to-draw-a-path-with-borders) was flagged with

> no effort is shown at all

and declined

how can we other way make SO better?

I have downvoted this question, but cannot delete it.

Is this question really ok?

Comment: You could have been a bit more descriptive.

Comment: I believe the concensus is that a flag should only be used if a mod needs to step in, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170945/flagged-question-for-low-quality-declined-was-i-wrong-to-flag-it?rq=1). Down-voting would be enough, maybe leave an comment to point out the no effort issue. This is a corner case because questions with a bounty cann't get close-voted. That's where a moderator might step in but only triggerd by this post

Comment: That really is a low-quality question. On the bright side, the bounty system seems to be working.

Comment: And I'd say that now is a bit too late to refund the bounty and close the Q. There's a top quality Answer, quite worth 100 points.

Comment: @Bart why should I use more words for something can be explained with less words. I wrote "no effort shown at all" Please provide a better comment for this flag Bart

Comment: Done @MikroDel. See my answer.

Comment: @MikroDel: If you're going to call people out for not showing effort, you should probably show more effort in your flags yourself. Just sayin'.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn and what do you mean I have done or doing wrong? I havent understand your irony.

Comment: Bolt is saying that the flag text "no effort is shown at all" shows no effort at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brad Larson:

> While not the best question in the world...
>   Two users left detailed and lengthy answers in response to the offered bounty, and to remove the potential of earning that would be unfair to those answerers.

So it's fine to advocate bad questions because they had a good answer?  Or was it the bounty?

This is not the Stack way I always see, and in fact I have lost rep on SO, when a question was removed even though I placed a decent answer.

So is it a case of if there's a bounty you can get away with answering a poor question and gain some rep?
What about my answer on a poor question? It was my early days and so I've now learned not to answer poor questions, but perhaps it was a FANTASTIC answer, better than any other ever posted.
Was that evaluated in the close process? Could users not have seen my amazing answer and thought bounty or not, that should stay? I know the answer is no...

Or if there was a bounty on the question I answered, would I have instead gained rep?

Users simply shouldn't answer on a poor question, bounty or not. They should instead flag it, or edit it, or downvote and ignore it.

I know bounties are precious but they shouldn't be allowed to be used to circumvent posting a rubbish question.
Closing it down and the answerers losing their time will teach them not to post on poor questions and instead spend that time voting to close or perhaps editing the question.

Ideally, they'd have edited the question and then posted an answer...

@MikroDel As for why your flag was denied, maybe if a bit more info was provided, as Bart said, and thus you provide a more solid and viable case for it being closed it might have been reviewed differently.
Although maybe not in this case and the mod who denied your flag accepted the question was not great.

I see the reasons for leaving this one open, truly, but I think it would still have been fair to close it as many other people lose rep when answering bad questions that are closed.

Comment: Read the answer of [Bernd Larson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204191/201575) please. He denied my flag cause of bounty

Answer (score 12):

I agree, not a great question. And I would normally have voted to close it as well. But your flag does not give a moderator a lot to go one. "So it shows no effort? Well, then vote accordingly".

If you're going to use a custom flag, be clear. State what the problem is, state what you want to happen and why a moderator will have to step in. Something along the lines of:

> This question shows no effort on behalf of the OP, and really  needs to be closed. It seems it has escaped the attention of the community, and now has a bounty on it, preventing closure. Perhaps this can be refunded, and the question closed?

Then you're clear, and a moderator does not have to guess or research. It's no guarantee for success (perhaps the moderator had other reasons to decline, the fact that it attracted answers for example), but less likely to be declined for it being unclear.

Comment: Sure I can write is this way - I will simply copy and paste your sample next time

Comment: And aslo Bart - why havent you downvoted the question from my example? (as for now)

Comment: I tend to hold back on voting on content because it has been brought up on Meta. I might, but Meta attention usually exaggerates the count.

Comment: Brad Larson declined it cause of bounty (http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204191/201575)

Comment: @MikroDel I can see how the answers received save the question. If you would have come in earlier, I think there would have been no discussion.

Comment: For all users voting up for this answer - my flag was declined not cause I have described it wrong, but cause of bounty. Take a look at the moderator  [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204191/201575)   who declined it

Comment: So, what's the problem? If that is the correct/preferred answer, then accept it.

Comment: The problem I see is that we have under http://stackoverflow.com/about a point "Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)" are not belongs to SO. But with bounty it is ok. It is maybe lack of functionallity for this case. It is some kind of double standarts for posts with and without bounties

Comment: That's not what I meant. You're addressing users who upvote me, and recommend they look at another answer. Either you think it's the correct answer, in which case accepting would be nice (and would float it to the top) or it's pointless to address those who think my answer has value.

Answer (score 7):

I declined that flag. While not the best question in the world, I saw no need for a moderator to step in and manually refund the bounty there.

Two users left detailed and lengthy answers in response to the offered bounty, and to remove the potential of earning that would be unfair to those answerers.

As far as the question goes, I could see this being significantly improved with an edit. As the answers indicate, I think it could be something of interest to future visitors. Not all short questions are terrible.

Others have commented on this, but you went through and flagged 7 other question with "no effort is shown at all", which doesn't provide us much to go on. These look like flags asking us to close questions, which we prefer to go through the close vote queue. You didn't indicate for any of these (which were all bountied questions) why we should step in and manually refund the bounty.

Comment: crap will be deleted crap + bounty not

Comment: @MikroDel - Do you honestly believe [user2558882's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19760652/19679) should be deleted? That's a fine reward for them taking the time to contribute good content.

Comment: No. Not this one. I honestly believe that system doesnt work if we have such a [queustions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19711616/502950) with bounty

Comment: @MikroDel The "system" that doesn't work in that case is the one that let it exists for long enough to have a bounty put on it.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I mean.