# Make it possible to delete crap questions with bounty and avoid double standards

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties

The example of such a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711616/how-to-draw-a-path-with-borders). It has -6 (minus six) as for the moment.

It was not deleted cause of bounty as moderator explains in his [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204191/201575)

The problem is if some very bad question is already answered and bounty is awarded it cannot be deleted - cause someone already invested time to answer it and received the bounty.

If we go the way we have at the moment it means we have double standards. The question I have linked is a good example for https://stackoverflow.com/about

> Don't ask about...
>   Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Maybe we can use some extra queue for bounty questions?

Comment: -7, but the answer seems decent at first glance (not that it deserves the rep)

Comment: @JanDvorak - On what grounds does the answer not "deserve" the rep?

Comment: I meant saying "I'm not sure that it deserves the rep", not that I think otherwise.

Comment: maybe we should introduce new tag "crap with bounty"

Comment: @MikroDel - So what is your view on Brad's point in your linked answer? "As far as the question goes, I could see this being significantly improved with an edit. As the answers indicate, I think it could be something of interest to future visitors. Not all short questions are terrible.". He doesn't actually say that he can't delete it because of the bounty at all.

Comment: @MartinSmith - my view is - the answers for this questions can be interesting for someone. The question itself should be deleted cause of "Don't ask about... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"

Comment: @MikroDel - You say "the answers for this questions can be interesting for someone". Deleting the question would of course delete the answers as well. "show your work" is primarily of use to the answerers so they can avoid doing something that the OP has tried and found not suitable. It is of little interest to future visitors to see the OP's non working code.

Comment: @MartinSmith thats why the discussion is started to find some solution. Or SO http://stackoverflow.com/about should be edited. With something like - "this question will only deleted if no one will answer it"

Comment: @MartinSmith and also I not agree that after the question was edited is a good one. Its crap. "I want A, B, C. Do it for me" This is the question I see it even after edit.

Comment: @MikroDel - The question hasn't been edited since Brad's answer. He doesn't say it is a good question now. Just that it could be edited into shape and that it is not unsalvageable such that it warrants moderator deletion.

Comment: The situation is not "a moderator doesn't want to delete a bad question because of a bounty". When you raised that issue, the question already had good answers. Good answers that might have come from the bounty. What would you want to happen at that point? Only remove the bounty? That's going to make answerers unhappy. Just close it? That can happen after the bounty as well. Delete it? Then you're deleting something which by now has value. The community simply was too late for that one. That's the only problem.

Comment: @Bart - and thats why this discussion was started. Maybe we will find the way to to avoid it in the future

Comment: But then your focus is the wrong one. There is no bounty problem here.

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't show much effort, that is certainly correct. But it is answerable and not among the really terrible questions that we have certainly enough of. And if that question is so terrible, why wasn't it closed in the three days before it got the bounty?

It also received answers that look pretty good to me, do you really think removing those answers along with the question will improve SO?

Removing a bounty is an action that will always have significant side-effects and that has an enormous potential for abuse. That is the main reason why it is mod-only, and it should stay that way in my opinion. It is also a rare case because most terrible questions are closed in the two days before a bounty can be started.

If you refund a bounty on a question you're giving the asker an unfair advantage as they gain most of the benefits of a bounty (greater exposure) without paying the price. If you refund the bounty after some good answers were posted, you're cheating those answerers out of their reward.

Comment: the answers for it are ok. The question itself is a bad one. Thats why I have started this discussion. Maybe we will find some opportunity to solve it in the future. For example one additional review queue for bounty questions.

Comment: @MikroDel Bad questions with bounties are very rare, and they indicate that the community moderation already failed. The current tools are sufficient to deal with those rare cases, I see no need for any additional queues.

Comment: I dont mean "please make one more queue" it is only discussion.

Comment: And why do you mean it is "very rare"? And what is for you the definition of "rare" in this case?

Comment: As you can see  [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199190/why-cannot-this-question-with-an-open-bounty-be-closed) 4 from 11 bounty question flagged are accepted.